# Anderenhelfen vs. Anderen helfen

Tags: spelling

Könnte man mir sagen, wie die richtige Schreibweise hier ist:
"Anderen helfen" oder "Anderenhelfen gibt einem ein gutes Selbstgefühl."

Hier stellt sich der Zusammenhang "Anderen" und "helfen" als Substantiv, daher wäre Anderenhelfen logischerweise die richtige Schreibweise. Könnte man mir bestätigen (mit Erklärung), welche die richtige ist.

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage nicht genau, aber "Anderenhelfen" gibt es in der deutschen Sprache nicht.

Comment: Impliziert helfen nicht ohnehin, dass jemand anderes da involviert ist?

Comment: wenn du den Prozess, anderen zu helfen, als Substantiv beschreiben willst, wäre "das Anderenhelfen" vermutlich ein der deutschen Grammatik / Rechtschreibung entsprechender Neologismus. In allen anderen Fällen schreibt man die beiden Wörter getrennt.

Comment: @Janka Selbshilfebücher...

Comment: Genau deshalb gibt es wohl die *Selbsthilfe*, aber nicht die *Anderenhilfe*. *Fremdhilfe* gibt es zwar, aber das ist etwas, das man erhält.

Comment: Das ist ja zum Fremdschämen hier! :)

Answer (score 8):

Auch wenn die deutsche Sprache Substantive anscheinend lieber mag als andere Wortarten, so machen wir doch nicht aus allem eins...

Nimmt man an, es gäbe die Substantivierung "Anderenhelfen", dann müsste es auch das Verb "anderenhelfen", dass hier substantiviert würde, geben (es gibt "anderen Helfen", was hier angebrachter wäre).

Mehrere Dinge sprechen dagegen:

1. Die gängige Substantivierung von "helfen" ist *Hilfe*. Es gibt z.B. das Substantiv "Fremdhilfe", das genommen wird, wenn man fremde Hilfe in Anspruch nimmt: "Der Wagen steckte so tief im Schlamm, dass er ohne Fremdhilfe nicht weiterkam". Für "Hilfe" an andere nimmt man einfach das Substantiv "Hilfe" - siehe "Hilfsbereitschaft".
2. Ein zusammengesetztes Verb "anderenhelfen" existiert nicht. Warum nicht? §33-34 der Rechtschreibregeln sagen, wie zusammengesetzte Verben gebildet werden - Einige Aspekte, die dabei wichtig sind, sind, dass (1) "Verbbestandteile die Merkmale von frei vorkommenden Wörtern" (§33) oder "selbstständiger Substantive" (§34) verloren haben" (z.B. *heimsuchen*, *stattfinden*)- "in allen anderen Fällen wird getrennt geschrieben".

Die Regeln für Zusammen- und Getrenntschreibung sind Regeln mit vielen Ausnahmen. Sie versuchen, jahrhundertelangen Sprachgebrauch in fixe Regeln zu fassen - "anderenhelfen" kommt im jahrhundertealten Sprachgebrauch eben einfach nicht vor. Wahrscheinlich, weil sich ein Wort entwickelt hat, dass für deinen Zweck viel besser geeignet ist: "Hilfsbereitschaft", das nicht voraussetzt, dass die Hilfe auch angenommen wird.

Comment: Ich gehe davon aus, dass der Fragesteller tatsächlich die Substantivierung des Verbs meint, also: "Seine liebsten Beschäftigungen waren das Laufen, das Schreiben und das Anderen Helfen." Wie es sich in diesem Fall mit Groß- und Kleinschreibung und Zusammen- und Getrenntschreibung verhält, weiß ich leider nicht, gehe aber davon aus, dass man "das **H**elfen" in diesem Fall groß schreiben muss.

Comment: @MartinRosenau yep, sehe ich auch so. Aber um ein Verb substantivieren zu können, muss es das erstmal geben...

Comment: Allerdings kann man ein substantiviertes Verb mit einem anderen Substantiv zusammensetzen. Beispiele: Alpenglühen, Muscheltauchen, Hammerwerfen, ...

Comment: @tofro Danke für Ihre Antwort. Die §33-34 der Rechtschreibregeln besagen nicht, wie die Schreibweise des aus mehreren Wortarten bestehenden Substantivs ist, sondern nur wann man einem Verb eine andere Wortart als Präfix anfügen darf. Bei der Substantivierung von Verben kann man einem Verb andere Wortarten (Partikeln, Adverbien, Substantiven und auch andere Verben) anhängen. (da kenn ich die Regel nicht, ich nenne hierbei Beispiele)

Comment: @tofro bspw.: "beim Nichtansprechen an dem Medikament" (nichtansprechen gibt's nicht) (Partikel), das Weggehenwollen (weggehenwollen gibt's auch nicht) (Zwei Verben), das Immerwiederkehren (Zwei Adverbien mit einem Verb), das Altwerden, das Neubauen....

Comment: Wir bilden i.A. dann ein neues Substantiv, wenn es etwas anderes (spezifischeres) bedeutet als die Auseinanderschreibung (*Alpenglühen* - dabei glühen die Alpen nur bildlich, *Hammerwerfen* - dabei wird kein beliebiger Hammer geworfen, sondern man meint die Sportart, bei "anderen Helfen" sehe ich keine Notwendigkeit für die Bildung eines neuen Kompositums. "Nichtansprechen", "Weggehenwollen" und "Immerwiederkehren" betrachte ich nicht auch nicht grade als stilistisch sinnvolle Wortfindungen.

Answer (score 2):

Sicherlich würden die meisten den Infinitiv mit *zu* verwenden:

> „Anderen zu helfen, macht ein gutes Selbstgefühl.”

Dennoch ist es keineswegs falsch, zu schreiben:

> „Anderenhelfen macht ein gutes Selbstgefühl.”

Hierbei geht es um den Prozess des Helfens, weshalb das Verb *helfen* substantiviert wird, und dieser Prozess wird durch das Indefinitpronomen *ander* näher beschrieben, einfach indem man das Indefinitpronomen und das Substantiv zusammensetzt. Zusammensetzungen mit substantivierten Verben sind vielleicht nicht häufig, aber es gibt sie, insbesondere in Form von substantivierten Infinitivgruppen<sup>1</sup>: das *Bücherschreiben*, das *Briefeschreiben*, das *Teetrinken*, das *Sichverlieben*, das *Außersichsein*, das *Tennisspielen*, das *Miteinanderringen* u.s.w.

<sup><sup>1</sup> vgl. den Eintrag [Substantivierung#Komposita](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivierung#Komposita) auf Wikipedia</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Die richtige Ausdrucksweise ist mit zu: "Es macht ein gutes Gefühl, anderen zu helfen!", "Anderen zu helfen, gibt ein gutes Gefühl.", "Es ist befriedigend, anderen zu helfen!" - Es handelt sich um eine Infinitivgruppe, nicht um eine Substantivierung. Wenn Sie den Sinn mit einem Substantiv vermitteln, erzeugen Sie ein höheres Sprachniveau. Dazu könnten Sie schreiben: "Altruismus erzeugt stets eine gewisse Befriedigung."